# Create specific mail directory system user

Tags: 14.04, postfix, dovecot

I have to create a new system user with specific mail directory inside folder like `/var/wwww/user/maildir`

I have tried `chown` command to assign mail directory to user but my mails are being bounced for new created system users.

One of the user is working fine as that was created on sendmail and later I have transfered it to postfix.

```
root@veezphone:~# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 20480000
mydestination = myhostname localhost.$mydomain $mydomain
myhostname = myhostname
mynetworks = 127.0.0.1, x.x.x.x
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_host_lookup = native
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

Comment: The most important thing for debugging such an issue is reading the mail log (`/var/log/mail.log`).

Comment: @JensErat There is nothing in mail.log file

Comment: Your Maildir is $userhome/Maildir, what's the homepath of your systemuser. Does the path exist? If not there won't be any mails being received since postfix can't just create a home out of nowhere since it doesn't have the rights for it.

Comment: If there is no mail log (did you reconfigure logging on that machine?), are you sure incoming mail is actually handled by this server and not some other?

Comment: User exist as stated in question for another user mail directory and mail received for that user